# Растянуть DIV по высоте родителя

Tags: css, вёрстка

Ребят, как растянуть все DIVы по высоте родителя при условии:

1. Высота родителя определяется высотой самого длинного DIVа.
2. Flexbox не подходит, т. к. в Safari не справляется. К сожалению...
3. Все, подобное `display: table-cell` не работает.

Всю голову сломал.
Код этого куска:

```css
.main_3_item {
  float: left;
  height: auto;
  background: white;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: left;
  font-family: 'OpenSans';
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 16px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  outline: 8px solid black
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="main_3_item col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <p>Подготовительная консультация.</p><span>&nbsp;</span> Во время её юрист может уже очертить для себя круг проблем, которые необходимо будет решить. Заказчик и консультант определяются с юрисдикцией, пакетом услуг, необходимой документацией и т.д.
  </div>

  <div class="main_3_item col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <p>Непосредственно регистрация.</p><span>&nbsp;</span> Благодаря большой сети международных партнёров и опыту в юридической сфере, компания осуществляет регистрацию оффшора и предоставляет всю необходимую документацию клиенту. Данная процедура занимает
    около 7-10 рабочих дней, начиная со дня проведения подготовительной консультации.
  </div>

  <div class="main_3_item col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <p>Дальнейшее юридическое сопровождение оффшорной компании.</p><span>&nbsp;</span> По окончании регистрации и передачи документов клиенту, компания нуждается в дальнейшем обслуживании, чтобы она держалась на плаву. Для этого мы готовы предоставить следующие
    услуги: оформление юридического адреса, услуга номинального директора/акционера, выплата госпошлин, содействие в открытии счёта в зарубежном банке, услуги аудита.
  </div>
</div>
```

- Все это нужно при помощи CSS
- Вот сайт — http://a0100957.xsph.ru/
- Вот один из таких блоков - http://joxi.ru/eAO0eLXFxaaG0r
- Вот как это было в Сафари с flexbox — http://joxi.ru/krD1qL6iEZZLkm, причем тут они благодаря flexbox все одинаковы по высоте

Comment: Если хотите получить помощь, покажите ваш HTML + CSS код!

Comment: Эм.. я же дал ссылку на сайт...

Comment: для получения помощи не целесообразно вставлять ссылки на пример кода (сторонний сайт), т.е при помощи вам, данный ответ может помочь и другим участникам у которых такая же проблема.По этой причине желательно вставлять код для наглядности!

Comment: понял, хорошо .. вывел куски кода

Answer (score 5, accepted):

У вас будет работать  `display: table-cell` если вы отключите `float`. Пока действует `float`, естественно, он перебивает `table-cell`

```css
.row {
  display: table
}
.row >div {
 display:table-cell;
 border:1px solid red;
 width:33%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div>
  123
  </div>
    <div>
  123
  </div>
    <div>
  orem Ipsum - это текст-"рыба", часто используемый в печати и вэб-дизайне. Lorem Ipsum является стандартной "рыбой" для текстов на латинице с начала XVI века. В то время некий безымянный печатник создал большую коллекцию размеров и форм шрифтов, используя Lorem Ipsum для распечатки образцов. 
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Хм.. благодарю! вот что я упустил..

Comment: Если ответ вас полностью устраивает, нажмите галочку напротив него